# fetch all files from S3 for the last N days in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get all files of a S3 directory using python for the last N days. I am using the below code where it fetches all the files in the directory.

```
folder = 'main'
subfolder = ['test','prod']
base= os.path.join(current_directory, 'project')
for i in subfolder:
   bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix="{}/{}".format(folder, i))
   for l in bucket_list:
      keyString = str(l.key)
      d = base + "/" + keyString
      l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
```

The below code provided only the last modified file. Is there any way we can get only the files that are modified or created in the last 2 days

```
for i in subfolder:
    bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix="{}/{}".format(folder, i))
    sorted_objs = sorted(bucket_list, key=attrgetter('last_modified'))
    latest = sorted_objs.pop()
    print(latest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using an **old version of boto**. These days you should be using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html).

Here is an example to get recent files using the **resource method:**

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

check_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days = 5)

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='my-prefix/')

recent_objects = [object.key for object in objects if object.last_modified > check_timestamp]

print(recent_objects)
```

Here is the same code using the **client method:**

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

check_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days = 5)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket',Prefix='my-prefix/')

recent_objects = [object['Key'] for object in response['Contents'] if object['LastModified'] > check_timestamp]

print(recent_objects)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However I am getting ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "prefix", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, Marker, MaxKeys, Prefix, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner. while running the recent objects.  objects = bucket.objects.filter(prefix="main/test/")
recent_objects = [object.key for object in objects if object.last_modified > check_timestamp]

Comment: Use `Prefix`, not `prefix`.